# Strange (webpack?) error "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Tags: javascript, webpack

Following syntax

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  userIsActive: getAccount() ? getAccount().status === "open" : false
};
```

Causes browser to throw `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` error, I pinpointed it to being syntax specific, getAccount() just returns object like

```
{
  status: "open"
}
```

Changing to this works perfectly fine, even returns correct data

```
const accStatus = () => {
  try {
    return getAccount() ? getAccount().status === "open" : false;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return false;
  }
};

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  userIsActive: accStatus
};
```

but I don't understand why it doesn't work in the first place?

**EDIT:** That catch statement is not triggered, which is odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, `userIsActive` is a boolean value, whereas in the second example it is a function that returns the boolean. This will probably work:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  userIsActive: () => getAccount() ? getAccount().status === "open" : false
};
```

Comment: `userIsActive` should resolve to a boolean returned by that ternary, so I assume it needs to execute, which is why I didn't wrap it other function

Comment: Considering the error message and the fact that the second example works, it looks like the code expects `userIsActive` not to be a boolean, but a thunk (i.e. a function that delays the actual computation of a value until you call it). This way you check if a user is active at any time by calling `state.userIsActive()`, whereas otherwise `state.userIsActive` would denote whether the user was active at the initialization of the app.